# With Arrow: How do I apply a transformation of type (X)->IO<Y> to data of type Sequence<X> to get IO<Sequence<Y>>?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I am learning functional programming using Arrow.kt, intending to walk a path hierarchy and hash every file (and do some other stuff). Forcing myself to use functional concepts as much as possible.

Assume I have a `data class CustomHash(...)` already defined in code. It will be referenced below.

First I need to build a sequence of files by walking the path. This is an impure/effectful function, so it should be marked as such with the `IO` monad:

```
fun getFiles(rootPath: File): IO<Sequence<File>> = IO {
   rootPath.walk() // This function is of type (File)->Sequence<File>
}
```

I need to read the file. Again, impure, so this is marked with `IO`

```
fun getRelevantFileContent(file: File): IO<Array<Byte>> {
   // Assume some code here to extract only certain data relevant for my hash
}
```

Then I have a function to compute a hash. If it takes a byte array, then it's totally pure. Making it `suspend` because it will be slow to execute:

```
suspend fun computeHash(data: Array<Byte>): CustomHash {
   // code to compute the hash
}
```

My issue is how to chain this all together in a functional manner.

```
fun main(rootPath: File) {
   val x = getFiles(rootPath) // IO<Sequence<File>>
      .map { seq -> // seq is of type Sequence<File>
         seq.map { getRelevantFileContent(it) } // This produces Sequence<IO<Hash>>
      }
   }
}
```

Right now, if I try this, `x` is of type `IO<Sequence<IO<Hash>>>`. It is clear to me why this is the case.

Is there some way of turning `Sequence<IO<Any>>` into `IO<Sequence<Any>>`? Which I suppose is essentially, probably getting the terms imprecise, taking blocks of code that execute in their own coroutines and running the blocks of code all on the same coroutine instead?

If Sequence weren't there, I know `IO<IO<Hash>>` could have been `IO<Hash>` by using a `flatMap` in there, but `Sequence` of course doesn't have that flattening of IO capabilities.

Arrow's documentation has a lot of "TODO" sections and jumps very fast into documentation that presumes a lot of intermediate/advanced functional programming knowledge. It hasn't really been helpful for this problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with arrow so I can't comment on that specifically, but you are looking for functions typically called `traverse` and/or `sequence` (note the lowercase 's', this is not the `Sequence` type).  A good description of these functions (for F#, but very readable nonetheless) is at the [F# for Fun and Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/) website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert the `Sequence` to `SequenceK` then you can use the `sequence` function to do that.

```
import arrow.fx.*
import arrow.core.*
import arrow.fx.extensions.io.applicative.applicative

val sequenceOfIOs: Sequence<IO<Any>> = TODO()

val ioOfSequence: IO<Sequence<Any>> = sequenceOfIOs.k()
    .sequence(IO.applicative())
    .fix()
```

Comment: This does not appear to be valid. When I paste your code into a scratch file in IDEA, "sequence" is underlined and I get the error message `expression sequence of type Sequence<IO<Any>> cannot be invoked as a function. The function invoke() is not found`

Comment: KSequence has a property `sequence` not a method. There does not appear to be a sequence function in KSequence.

Comment: Added the imports, maybe that helps

Comment: Yes, that made a difference. I think a different module had been imported when I pasted your code into a scratch file. I even inspected whatever the class was, and "IO.applicative" was a property not a method.

For anyone else coming here, it seems that the difference between `SequenceK.sequence` and `SequenceK.traverse` is that traverse allows you to also apply a lambda in the process to transform the—in my example—IO<Foo> into IO<Bar>.

Comment: `sequence` is `traverse` with  the `::identity` function